# Find Reduction formula

Tags: calculus, integration, reduction-formula

> Let $n$ be a fixed integer. Find a reduction formula for $$\int x^n\ln^k(x)\,dx$$ that relates $\int x^n\ln^k(x)\,dx$ to $\int x^n\ln^{k-1}(x)\,dx$.

What is this question asking for?

Am I just supposed to take the integral of it and leave it in terms of $k$ and $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By parts:

$$u=\log^kx\;,\;\;u'=\frac{k\log^{k-1}x}{x}\\v'=x^n\;,\;\;v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

and from here

$$I_{n,k}:=\int x^n\log^kxdx=\frac{x^{n+1}\log^kx}{n+1}-\frac{k}{n+1}I_{n,(k-1)}$$

Comment: how to i say or determine that i related those two integrals?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking...

Comment: @user71317:  the question asks for a relation between $I_{n,k}$ and $I_{n,k-1}$ and DonAntonio has provided it.  The idea is that if you are asked for $I_{n,k}$ you can step down through the $k$'s until you get to an integral you can do some other way.  In this case, if $k=0$ it is easy, so you apply this formula until you get there.